# Couldn't find User without an ID Hartl rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have problem with my project in rails
I am learning from railstutorial.org and i have problem in listing ~6.18 
So this is repo
https://github.com/Mroczeks/first_project
And this is error:

```
rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 10776
Started with run options --seed 33787

 FAIL["test_schould_be_valid", UserTest, 0.6801217989996076]
 test_schould_be_valid#UserTest (0.68s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/models/user_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserTest>'

ERROR["test_email_addresses_should_be_saved_as_lower-case", UserTest, 0.6879979369996363]
 test_email_addresses_should_be_saved_as_lower-case#UserTest (0.69s)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:         ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User without an ID
            test/models/user_test.rb:45:in `block in <class:UserTest>'

 FAIL["test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses", UserTest, 0.7056386839994957]
 test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses#UserTest (0.71s)
        "user@example.com" should be valid
        test/models/user_test.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UserTest>'
        test/models/user_test.rb:30:in `each'
        test/models/user_test.rb:30:in `block in <class:UserTest>'

  18/18: [=================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.78367s
18 tests, 29 assertions, 2 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: What's in the `test/models/user_test.rb` file?

Comment: Test for model users (name, email and pass in bcrypt) So i testing for example  the password is empty or has a designated number of characters.

Comment: https://github.com/Mroczeks/first_project/blob/master/test/models/user_test.rb

Answer (score 3):

The cause for this error seem to be failing validations when saving your `@user` object in user_test.rb file. Try replacing this test with below code and you will see the failing validation when running this test:

```
test "email addresses should be saved as lower-case" do
  mixed_case_email = "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM"
  @user.email = mixed_case_email

  # Calling `save!` here will raise an exception if failed to save @user.
  @user.save!
  assert_equal mixed_case_email.downcase, @user.reload.email
end
```

Fix your `setup` method to satisfy all validations accordingly and try again.

Answer (score 3):

In `User` model, you have [defined password length validation](https://github.com/Mroczeks/first_project/blob/master/app/models/user.rb#L9) to be 6 as minimum, but in test setup, [created the user](https://github.com/Mroczeks/first_project/blob/497d4da0d270d10c065de5d497a22ce7651de20e/test/models/user_test.rb#L6) with `password: 'pies'`. Hence you are getting all the errors and failures:

```
FAIL["test_schould_be_valid", UserTest, 0.6801217989996076]
test_schould_be_valid#UserTest (0.68s)
    Expected false to be truthy.
    test/models/user_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

---

To resolve all the errors, you need to initialize a user with valid data in `UserTest#setup`. In this case, you just need to provide a password with minimum length of 6.